# How to fix my brew doctor errors?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

Running brew doctor on my mountain lion terminal , I get the following errors :

```
Warning: /usr/local/etc isn't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew.

If a brew tries to write a file to this directory, the install will
fail during the link step.

You should probably `chown` /usr/local/etc
Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:

    /usr/local/share/man/man8
Warning: Your XQuartz (2.7.2) is outdated
Please install XQuartz 2.7.4.
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libicudata.49.1.2.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libicui18n.49.1.2.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libicuio.49.1.2.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libicule.49.1.2.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libiculx.49.1.2.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libicutest.49.1.2.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libicutu.49.1.2.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libicuuc.49.1.2.dylib
Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/icu-i18n.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/icu-io.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/icu-le.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/icu-lx.pc    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/icu-uc.pc
Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libc-client.a
Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your path.
Consider amending your PATH variable so it contains:
  /usr/local/sbin
```

How can I fix these errors?
Is it critical to fix them or I may ignore them?
Thank you.

Comment: I have already run 'brew update' before running 'brew doctor'.

Comment: I've managed to get rid of XQuartz error by using installing this : http://xquartz.macosforge.org/downloads/SL/XQuartz-2.7.4.dmg

Answer (score 0):

If you read the text carefully, you will realize that it actually tells you how to fix the errors:

```
You should probably `chown` /usr/local/etc

You should probably `chown` them:

    /usr/local/share/man/man8
```

dylibs, .pc files..

```
may need to be deleted
```

So, change the owner of the mentioned directory to your user, and delete the unwanted files (if you didn't put them there on purpose).